# how can i reduce my App size with database in android

Tags: android, database, size

I have an android app with a Test sqlite database. my test database size is 386 KB.
when i run my app in phone using test database and go to setting->app , I see this:

```
Total ........ 3.44 MB
App...........3.01 MB
Data..........0.41 MB
```

but when i use main database that has 34 MB size and i run my app in phone with main database and go to setting->app, I see this:

```
Total......69.86 MB
App.......20.6 MB
Data......49.26 MB
```

1. Why does my app size increase when my database size increase?
2. My database size out of app is 34 MB...why when I use in App increase Up to 49 MB?

Answer (score 1):

The Data figure is measured by both Database size + Preference size.
Maybe your app is having some shared preference that contributes to the Data size as you see.